# JavaME on Netbeans: All classes are duplicate classes

Tags: netbeans, java-me

I'm building a Java ME app on Netbeans. I'm using SVN and Mercurial. My problem is that all my classes are suddenly duplicates. I've tried `Clean and Build`, and just `Clean`, but it still won't work. I've run into an error with svn whining about it not being 1.7. I already set it to use TortoiseHG 1.7 in `Program Files`. I need help fixing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed it. Deleted Netbeans' cache which is located at `C:\Documents and Settings\username\.netbeans\7.0\var\cache`. I still get the subversion error, but I guess that's an unrelated issue.